# C++: Visit Any Type Holding Other Types (`std::any`, `std::variant`, etc.)

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, variant-type, visitor-pattern

### Intro

I want to visit the value held by a class, which could be of multiple types. This class is very similar to a `std::any`, so I will be using this in this question.

I wanted to create a reusable solution that accesses the value efficiently (without recursion, or unnecessary calls), that worked similarly to how `std::visit` works for `std::variant`.

### Function

This is what I have come up with:

```cpp
namespace detail {

    struct retriever {

        template <typename Type, typename Return, typename Visitor, typename Value>
        static Return get(Visitor&& visitor, Value&& value) {

            decltype(auto) innerValue = compatibility_layer<std::decay_t<Value>>::template get<Type>(std::forward<Value>(value));
            return std::invoke(std::forward<Visitor>(visitor), std::move(innerValue));
        }
    };
}

template <typename... Alternatives, typename Visitor, typename Value>
constexpr std::common_type_t<std::invoke_result_t<Visitor, Alternatives>...> visit(Visitor&& visitor, Value&& value) {

    using Return = std::common_type_t<std::invoke_result_t<Visitor, Alternatives>...>;

    constexpr std::array<bool(*)(const std::decay_t<Value>&), sizeof...(Alternatives)> compatibilityResult = {
        &compatibility_layer<std::decay_t<Value>>::template holds_alternative<Alternatives>...
    };

    if (auto compatibleType = std::find_if(std::begin(compatibilityResult), std::end(compatibilityResult), [&] <typename F> (F&& f) { return std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), value); });
        compatibleType != std::end(compatibilityResult)) {

        constexpr std::array<Return(*)(Visitor&&, Value&&), sizeof...(Alternatives)> retrievers = {
            &detail::retriever::get<Alternatives, Return, Visitor, Value>...
        };

        std::size_t index = std::distance(std::begin(compatibilityResult), compatibleType);
        return retrievers[index](std::forward<Visitor>(visitor), std::forward<Value>(value));
    }
    else {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Value does not hold any of the alternatives.");
    }
}
```

The inputs to the function are a visitor and the value to be visited. Also, as template arguments, you have to provide which types should be tested for compatibility (the types to visit).

The function uses a `compatibility_layer` class (which needs to be specialized for the type you want to support visiting (e.g., `std::any`), to:

- Determine whether the value holds a specific type
- Retrieve a certain type from the value

For `std::any`, the implementation would be like this:

```cpp
template <>
struct compatibility_layer<std::any> {

    template <typename T>
    constexpr static bool holds_alternative(const std::any& value) {
        return value.type() == typeid(T);
    }

    template <typename T>
    constexpr static decltype(auto) get(const std::any& value) {
        return std::any_cast<T>(value);
    }
};
```

We don't invoke `holds_alternative` for all the types provided in the template argument `Alternatives`, but only until we find a `true` value. We do this by iterating over a `std::array` (populated at compile-time) holding pointers to the respective static methods `holds_alternative`.

Similarly, we call `get` at most once, only for that type that is compatible. To map the compatible type to the `get` method to call, we create another `std::array` (also populated at compile-time) that holds pointers to the `get` methods. Then, we access the correct `get` method based on the index of the compatible type from the previous array.

### Example

In this example, I visit a `std::any` and a `std::variant` (just as a test - I know `std::visit` should be used for variants).

```cpp
namespace {

    template <typename T>
    void doVisit(T&& value) {

        auto visitor = [](auto &&v) { std::cout << "Made it! " << v << std::endl; };
        vac::visit<bool, int, double, std::string>(std::move(visitor), std::forward<T>(value));
    }
}

int main() {

    std::cout << "I am running" << std::endl;

    // Any example.
    std::any anyValue = std::string{"Any!"};
    ::doVisit(std::move(anyValue));

    // Variant example.
    std::variant<bool, int, double, std::string> variantValue = true;
    ::doVisit(std::move(variantValue));
}
```

The `compatibility_layer` for the variant is similar:

```cpp
template <typename... Ts>
struct compatibility_layer<std::variant<Ts...>> {

    template <typename T>
    constexpr static bool holds_alternative(const std::variant<Ts...>& value) {
        return std::holds_alternative<T>(value);
    }

    template <typename T>
    constexpr static decltype(auto) get(const std::variant<Ts...>& value) {
        return std::get<T>(value);
    }
};
```

### Feedback

The function does what I need, but I am not sure whether it's any better than a recursive function like:

```cpp
template <typename FirstAlternative typename... OtherAlternatives, typename Visitor, typename Value>
constexpr std::invoke_result_t<Visitor, FirstAlternative> visit(Visitor&& visitor, Value&& value) {

    if (compatibility_layer<std::decay_t<Value>>::template holds_alternative<FirstAlternative>(value)) {
        return detail::retriever::get<Alternatives, Return, Visitor, Value>(std::forward<Visitor>(visitor), std::forward<Value>(value));
    }
    else {

        if constexpr (sizeof...(OtherAlternatives) == 0) {
            throw std::invalid_argument("Value does not hold any of the alternatives.");
        }
        else {
            return visit<OtherAlternatives...>(std::forward<Visitor>(visitor), std::forward<Value>(value));
        }
    }
}
```

I wanted to avoid recursing, mainly to simplify debugging (as our `std::any` can hold 20 different types).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any issues with this code, except a slightly alternative way to implement it:

## Avoiding arrays

> I wanted to avoid recursing, mainly to simplify debugging (as our std::any can hold 20 different types).

Although recursion might actually result in the cleanest code here, I can see the point. However, creating arrays of function pointers is also not very nice in my opinion. The usual way you replace recursive templates since C++17 is by using fold expressions. We can do that here as well. Consider:

```
template <typename... Alternatives, typename Visitor, typename Value>
constexpr auto visit(Visitor &&visitor, Value &&value)
{
    using Return = std::common_type_t<std::invoke_result_t<Visitor, Alternatives>...>;
    Return (*retriever)(Visitor &&, Value &&) = {};

    ([&]{
        if (compatibility_layer<std::decay_t<Value>>::template holds_alternative<Alternatives>(value)) {
            retriever = &detail::retriever::get<Alternatives, Visitor, Value>;
        }
    }(), ...);

    if (retriever) {
        return retriever(std::forward<Visitor>(visitor), std::forward<Value>(value));
    } else {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Value does not hold any of the alternatives.");
    }
}
```

This could be improved by letting the lambda return a boolean, so you can short-circuit using `||`.

It is very unfortunate that `std::optional<void>` is not valid, otherwise I think having a `std::optional<Return> result` variable would make this code even cleaner.

## Visiting multiple variables at the same time

If you look at the documentation of [`std::visit()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit), you'll notice that it can take multiple variables as arguments. Consider that you might have a visitor that takes two or more arguments, like in:

```
std::variant<int, float> foo = 42;
std::any bar = 3.1415;
auto sum = visit<int, float, double>(
    [](auto a, auto b) -> double {return a + b;},
    foo, bar);
```

This is doable, but would of course complicate your code even more.

Comment: That is a great simplification! I have implemented the lambda expansion with short-circuiting and it does the job. Thanks for suggesting it!